# How to find the best algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I'm dealing with a problem here.

It says:Build an algorithm which takes two lists(the elements of the lists are natural numbers) and finds if every element of the first list is displayed at least once in the second list.

-What if the list is sorted?

An algorithm that can do this is by comparing every element of the first list with every element from the second list but I think there is an algorithm with a better complexity.

Can anyone give me any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: is the list sorted or not?

Comment: No,the list is unsorted but I just thought what if it is?

Comment: well if the list are sorted then u wouldn't have to compare every element of List1 with every element of list2. IN this case max. no. of comparision = Size of 2$^{nd}$ list

Answer (score 1):

For unsorted lists $A,B$, one starting point is beginning with the first element $a_0\in A$, cycle through the list $B$ comparing $a_0$ with $b_i\in B$ and for each $b_i\in B$ find whether this element is a maximum or minimum for list $B$.  Next, take the first element of $B$ and use the same process over $A$.  Then you have the following information: $min_A,max_A\in A,\ min_B,max_B\in B.$  Then you can find out rather quickly (for some items) whether they will be in the other list.  If $a_i\lt min_B\text{ or }a_i\gt max_B,\ a_i\notin B$.

Once these mins and maxes have been established, it is a quick process to reduce each list to be within the interval of the other, and you know that all items removed due to being "outside" the other list cannot be elements of it.  The fastest way I can think of to compare the two lists from here is to combine and sort them and search the combined list for duplicates.